# Left align table caption

Tags: r, gt

I added a `caption` to a table. Now, to `align` the title of the table you can use `opt_align_table_header(data, align = c("left", "center", "right"))`. Is such a function also available for a caption?

```
    # Download package    
    devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")
    # Load package     
    library(gt)    
    # Code        
    gt(head(mtcars), caption = 'This is table caption') %>%
              tab_header(title="Some Title", subtitle="Table 1: Mtcars with gt.")
```

Comment: Not reproducible, you should add `library()` calls!

Comment: In (my) `huxtable` package you can use `caption_pos`.

Comment: @jay.sf, I have edited the code as asked for, hope it works now.